# $addToSet implementation for array update on PATCH request

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Is there a way to tell MongoRepository to implement $addToSet when updating an array value during PATCH request?

I am using Spring data rest with HATEOAS and Mongodb, and the current implementation replaces the old array with the new array, where the desired functionality is to perform a union of both arrays and have that array stored in the Mongodb document.

While it should be possible to do that with custom implementation, Spring won't generate a rest url for the implementation and hence would require a lot of boilerplate for a rather small requirement. All responses appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data REST is build on top of domain objects and the repository abstraction. So letting it work with a store specific implementation is out of its scope. I am assuming your core goal is to apply a PATCH request to your domain instance and that `$addToSet` is just the means to achieve that.

Since version 2.2 M1 of Spring Data REST we support the [JSON Patch media type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) on PATCH request. So you can send the following document to the server:

```
[{ "op": "add", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": [ "foo", "bar" ] }]
```

Assuming `c` is the array your trying to manipulate, this would add `foo` and `bar` to it.

The other - more radical option is to actually deploy a manually implemented controller and hook it into the correct place in the URI space to manually interact with the repository.

Comment: @Olivier-gierke Thanks for your reply! I don't see 2.2 M1 available on maven. The latest is 2.1.1.RELEASE and on this version, the server throws a 405 upon sending it a similar document. Infact before your reply I was trying to implement a solution where a similar document is sent to the server and I use preHandle in an interceptor to process it. Do you believe it's a viable solution until 2.2 M1 is available? Thanks!

Comment: Milestones are available from the [Spring IO repositories](http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone).

Comment: @Olivier-gierke Got it, thanks! However I still get a 405 upon sending the document to the server using curl: `curl-i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"op": "add", "path": "/reminder/53c84d00b02ec66a1e328ccf/sendeeids","value":["dontreplace"]}' http://localhost:8080/` Only viable verbs seem to be GET, HEAD and OPTIONS. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The media type you need to send is `application/json-patch+json`.

Comment: @Olivier-gierke It still gave the same error. Then I changed the document and resource a bit as in the following curl : `curl -i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type:application/json-patch+json" -d '{"op": "add", "path": "/sendeeids","value":["dontreplace"]}' http://localhost:8080/reminder/53c84d00b02ec66a1e328ccf`. Now it doesn't give 405 but bad request, saying it couldn't read the object of the pojo(com.company.prod.pojo.Reminder) used to define the resource referred to by `http://localhost:8080/reminder/53c84d00b02ec66a1e328ccf` in the curl request. Is there an example/tutorial about this somewhere?

Comment: Can you gist the exception you get?

Comment: I am working on a better error message currently. The error is caused by an invalid path actually. To append an item to the array, you need to use `/sendeeids/-` (see [the spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902#appendix-A.16) for details).

Comment: @Olivier-gierke Since I need to add an element to an existing array, I am following this link : http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902#appendix-A.2 . However, this throws the same error. Debugging shows it blows at line 107 in JsonPatchHandler, trying to get the list of operations, which I thinks shouldn't fail with the curl : `curl -i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type:application/json-patch+json" -d '{"op": "add", "path": "/sendeeids/1","value":"dontreplace"}' http://localhost:8080/reminder/3c84d00b02ec66a1e328ccf`. Thoughts?

Comment: @Olivier-gierke I am stuck with this since the weekend and can't go forward. Is there any test case in the code that shows this working or any sort of tutorial that I can compare my approach against?

Comment: @Olivier-gierke Resolved. Turns out that even though the there is a single operation to be sent to the server, it has to be included inside "[]". I have added a test for "add" operation in JsonPatchHandlerUnitTests class. Let me know if you want a pull request.

Comment: Good point. I'll tweak my answer accordingly. Thanks for accepting! :)