# How to add resource and specify related element?

Tags: rest, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have a simple API for a game tip website:

- `/class` is the endpoint for in game classes
- `/tip` is the endpoints for the tips
- `/user` is the endpoint for the users

Each tip has 3 relations:

- `(:User)-[:AUTHORED]-(:Tip)`
- `(:Class)<-[:FOR]-(:Tip)`
- `(:Class)<-[:AGAINST]-(:Tip)`

When I create a Tip using `POST`, I do'nt know how to add relations at the create time.

I can do this way: [Add relation to another node in SDN4 + REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522831/add-relation-to-another-node-in-sdn4-rest) after creating the resource, but I want to do it with only one query.

EDIT:
I tried to POST this:

```
'{"content":"TEST", "forClass":"/class/2", "againstClass":"/class/2"}'
```

and the item has been created, no InvalidArgument Exception raised, but if I go to my class resource's tips, I don't have any tips:

`GET /class/2/tips`:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "tip" : [ ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/class/2/tips"
    }
  }
}
```

`GET /tip/9` (the created one):

```
{
  "content" : "TEST",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/tip/9"
    },
    "tip" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/tip/9"
    },
    "author" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/tip/9/author"
    },
    "againstClass" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/tip/9/againstClass"
    },
    "forClass" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/tip/9/forClass"
    }
  }
}
```

`GET /tip/9/forClass`:

```
{
  "name" : null,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/class/2"
    },
    "bnSClass" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/class/2"
    },
    "tips" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/class/2/tips"
    }
  }
}
```